# can IOBluetooth framework be used for bluetooth low energy?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

Can i use IOBluetooth framework on MAC os to communicate with Bluetooth low energy devices?

http://secutyhf.org/wordpress/zebel/2014/12/25/difference-between-corebluetooth-framework-and-iobluetooth-framework/

Link says that CoreBluetooth framework is for Bluetooth low energy and IOBluetooth framework for classic bluetooth interface.

But in IOBluetooth framework one can see the coreBluetooth framework available.
This is quite confusing.

I am new to MAC os application development. Inputs will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IOBluetooth is for Bluetooth Classic and BLE on OS X. CoreBluetooth is for BLE on iOS.

Comment: I have the same question. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Yea The CoreBluetooth Framework is designed only for Low Energy Bluetooth Devices (Which are referred to as Peripherals) whereas the IOBluetooth Framework is designed to search mainly for Classic Bluetooth Devices but Yes, also Low Energy Bluetooth Devices (by setting searchType to *kIOBluetoothDeviceSearchLE*).

However, The IOBluetooth Framework will not return all the Low Energy devices than that of what CoreBluetooth would. I am not sure why this is at this point but I am currently looking into this.

Hope this is a bit of useful info.